# IIS7 Connection to SQL 2008 not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, database-connection

Having trouble getting my local IIS7 running C # MVC app to connect to a newly installed Sql 2008. IT was working wiht SQL Express, but we upgraded every machine to full SQL. Now, just my machine, will not connect to SQL 2008.

Followed many websites info, fooled wiht the user account both in IIS7 and SQL2008. Setting permissions to the DB's with db_owner(actually selected every permission) just not connecting.

I noticed the w3wp.exe service is not running. Not sure if that is the issue or if it was even running before.

Messed with the and tried all the sugeestions and  tutorials out there that had to do with
Application pools are running, their set to the proper settings 
IIs Account NetorkServices
Sql NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
created users for IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0

When i check the sql logs there is no sign of it even trying to connect. The only message i get is when i restart IIs. Just says starting and stopping.

Been thru this before when i first tried to connect to SQL express, and was not this hard, and i did not touch anything in IIs when i installed sql 2008. So it should have connected.

Any other suggestions out there?

Comment: Is sql on the same machine as iis?

Comment: Yes. And it is working on the other devs machines.

Comment: It does work when i use VS2010, i can run the project from there. But there are a few things that we require IIs testing for. Not major, BUt i like the way my setup was running before, we have multiple apps, and iusig VS i i have run each app to go between them. When using localhost/IIs I'm able to go between them like to the site naturally would.

Comment: Can you provide your connection string? Do you have sql express and full version installed simultaneously? How are their instance names?

Comment: The conn string is buried somewhere in LLBL. I can connect thru VS, so the conn works fine. No, removed express before installing. Only sql 2008 r2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirectly you lead me to the solution. lol
Started searching on running IIs and Sql 2008 on the same machine.

Running on a Win7 64bit, IIS7 an sql2008 R2.
Long story short, after hours and hours of fighting with IIS and SQL.

IIS7 --> Application Pools --> Select your pool --> Advanced settings --> General tab --> Enable 32-bit Applications set to true.

How it got to false, or why sqlexpress worked and sql2008 did not, not sure. But this fixed the issue.

Comment: Your issue was not sql and connection to it, but your build configuration changed to 32-bit. 

What is also possible, but not probable is that 32-bit only version of sql was installed, and it is of newer version than your sql express, so there were no 32-bit assemblies of referenced libraries (Microsoft.Sql....)

Answer (score 0):

LLBL DataAccessAdapter should have string property ConnectionStringKeyName which contains app settings key (in web.config), which contains connection string. Visual studio does not use that connection string and you being able to connect to db from VS does not mean that connection string your application uses is valid.